# WebSphere 8.5.6: MDB XAException method xa_start errorcode -7

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, xa

we have upgraded from WAS 5 to WAS 8.5.5.6. We are still using our EAR application with no problem, the only thing that we have changed is the JDBC Provider, now we use the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver (XA).

This EAR, contains a MDB that is used in a message listener service with MQ 5 that is hosted in another server.

We put one, two and four hundred messages and they are received Ok in WAS and all works fine.

One day after, we put the same messages and we get an error. The message listener service is in started state. [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25756497/MQError.txt) is the full message.

We enable MQ trace on WAS and get [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25756497/LogsStack.zip) error files.

If we restart the message listener service all the messages are consumed.

Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error XAER_RMFAIL but in my case the problem was communication between two EJBs each one on different WAS. The solution was to set trusted realms between both servers (from server1 to server2 and server2 to server1).

To find out what is the problem I recommend enabling MQ trace on WAS ([Enabling Java Message Service (JMS) trace for WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199176)). Also check FFDC logs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I followed the tip and [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25756497/LogsStack.zip) are the LOGs files. Two things to comment: 

1) With MQ 7.5.4 and SQLJDBC 4.0 for SQL Server 2012, the same EAR works fine without this type of error. The problem its with MQ 5.3.
2) Before the migration, The EAR was using the DataDirect JDBC driver for SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing that we have changed is the JDBC Provider, now we use the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver (XA).

Stack trace:

```
javax.resource.ResourceException: enlist: caught Exception
```

I think you have identified your problem - it's the change in the JDBC provider.

Well, that and also the fact of MQ 5.x version being end-of-life since 2007.  The [System Pre-Reqs for v5.3](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006285) don't list support for MSSQL Server at all.  Any reason to upgrade WAS but leave MQ at an out-of-date version that doesn't support the other technology used?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Before the migration we used the DataDirect JDBC driver for SQL 2005 without problems. Now we use the SQLJDBC 4.0 driver for SQL Server 2012. We are planning to upgrade our MQ to 7.5.4 in the short term, but first we have to resolve this issue. We enabled MQ trace on WAS and [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25756497/LogsStack.zip) are the LOGs files.

Comment: "...upgrade our MQ to 7.5.4 in the short term, but first we have to resolve this issue." Fall back to the working configuration and test the new stuff in a sandbox environment.

Comment: We do not find a solution under the above configuration, so we opted to migrate to MQ 7.5 and tests were satisfactory. Thanks.